# What are some 3D games written in C#?

Tags: c#, 3d

I've been searching on Google for some C# programs. I have found Paint.NET. Is that the only C# program out there? What about games? Someone have a link to 3D game in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) and/or [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/), two spen source .NET managed IDE.

Also, as others stated, there are plenty C# OSS frameworks that you can study. Here is a [first list](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/overview.html).

Answer (score 11):

Quake was ported to C#/Silverlight: http://www.innoveware.com/quakelight.html

#### Play it now: http://www.innoveware.com/ql3/QuakeLight.html

Answer (score 6):

If you want to write games for Windows or the XBox360 you can use [XNA](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/)... also their are tons of apps all over the place that use C#.  You can also find projects that were written in .Net on [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/)

[XNA - Game Studio](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/)

Answer (score 2):

A very good resource is the [XNA Creators Club](http://creators.xna.com/).

This has some great resources for learning (the starter kits for XNA are full games, with artwork, written in C#).  In addition, there is a community driven site full of examples of 2D and 3D games written in C#.

Answer (score 1):

check [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com)

Answer (score 1):

[SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/develop/) might be a good place to start. On the projects page select C# as the programming language and search. There are currently about 17,000 C# projects.

Browsing the the source for a large project may be a bit daunting if you are learning - I'd recommended trying to find something simple to start with.

Edit:
Another couple of quick links to games

- [Sudoku in C#](http://www.personalmicrocosms.com/Pages/np.aspx)
- [Gem Towers](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=421929) (much more ambitious 3D C# game)

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at Unity3D - it uses Mono to let games run on Mac and PC.
All behavioral code is written in C#. There are games by both EA and Cartoon Network as well as loads of corporate and indie games based on Unity.
[Unity 3D Game List](http://unity3d.com/gallery/game-list/)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some 3D engines and whatnot created in c#:

http://www.multiverse.net/index.html ([Reference to C#](http://www.multiverse.net/platform/Under%20the%20Hood.ppt))
http://axiomengine.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page
http://www.visual3d.net/